# ping always suceeds - even on non-existing domains

Tags: centos, dns, ping

Working on CentOS7 - after entering non-existing domain:

```
# ping dfgsdfgsdfsdf.sd
```

The answer is (mail.xsistema.lt is local domain, machine name):

```
PING dfgsdfgsdfsdf.sd.xsistema.lt (192.168.0.55) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mail.xsistema.lt (192.168.0.55): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
64 bytes from mail.xsistema.lt (192.168.0.55): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
64 bytes from mail.xsistema.lt (192.168.0.55): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe something related to this? https://serverfault.com/questions/513237/nslookup-fails-but-ping-succeeds-for-nonexistent-domains

Comment: Yes, by changing the host name from `mail.xsistema.lt` to `mail` problem is solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an option in `/etc/resolv.conf` that adds a domain (`xsistema.lt`) automatically to any name that does not exist.

Since `dfgsdfgsdfsdf.sd` does not exist, it gets in fact converted to `dfgsdfgsdfsdf.sd.xsistema.lt`.

And this resolves for any name because there is a DNS wildcard in the zone:

```
$ dig '*.xsistema.lt' +short
88.119.185.129
```